# is there a way to look for same values by month by month in R?

Tags: r, date

I'll start by showing a part of my dataframe.

So I have for each patient a combination of molecules, the date he started it and the theoretical date he/she finishes the treatment.

[image]

What I need to do is the flag/get the patients who stays under same combination of molecules for at least six consecutive months. 
I already found a way to create sequences of dates between to dates and create a new df with it..but I don't know to do the last part of getting the patients on the same treatment for six consecutive months with R.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt to solve your question. However, I think it's possible with an `apply` function, but I didn't found it yet.

```
library(lubridate)
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2), traitement = c("A+B+C","D+E"),
                begin =  c('01/03/2012','01/01/2012'),
                end =  c('05/06/2012','05/07/2012'),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$begin = dmy(df$begin)
df$end = dmy(df$end)
df$time = 0
df$toolong = FALSE

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$time[i] = month(as.period(interval(df$begin[i],df$end[i]))) # compute the number of months
  if(df$time[i] >= 6){df$toolong[i] = TRUE} # flag with true patient you use medication for too long
}
df
```

Comment: Hello Gowachin,
Thank you very much for your proposed solution. It is indeed a good one.
What if I want that the begin and end be the min of start_date and end be the max of end_date for each patient and molecule combination (a group by if you see what I mean).

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand your second question about `min` and `max`. What column do you want to group by ? Molecule combination or time ?

Comment: If my answer is good for your question, you can also mark it as answered ;)